# What effect or style is being used in the "Daydreamer" by Bipolar Sunshine?

Tags: style

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JhBa8LekChU It's also used in some of the Tame Impala videos; does anyone know what **that** is?

Comment: Hello and welcome to GD.SE. The question very vague, you dont specify which effect your looking for this mean that unless you edit your question to specify, what effect your looking for then this question will be most likely be closed.

Comment: So you see a baldy scoped question gets useless answers and closure. [Edit](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/107819/edit) your question

Comment: As joojaa said, you need to [edit] your question to be a lot clearer. At the very least include a screenshot of what effect you're referring to. Please take a minute to read through the [help] to see how the site works too, specifically [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](/help/dont-ask). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

looks like animation done with hand painted elements.